# How to use tab to draw multiple diagrams at the same time

Tags: javascript, tabs, diagram, gojs

I am using the " GoJS" library.

I'd like multi diagram make with tab.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqnTL.png)

I made the following

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2E6g.png)

Draw a diagram by dragging and dropping the shape from the palette on the left.
It is possible to control multiple diagrams simultaneously by switching tabs.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XumGy.png)

Every time I changed the tab,  used in the " Go JS " changes.

It seems to be working normally. In addition, even as the tab is switched, the existing diagram can not disappear and can be drawn again later.
I seem to have accomplished what I wanted to do.
However, if you check it in the debug mode, you will see the following error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JM2aV.png)

Invalid div id; div already has a Diagram associated with it.
go-debug.js (32,15)

This is my code.

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                            <!-- <li class="active"><a href="#mainProcedure" data-toggle="tab" onclick="switchTab('mainProcedure')">Main Procedure</a></li> -->
                            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Main Procedure<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="main">
                                    <li><a class='switchTab' href="#mainProcedure" data-toggle="tab" onclick="switchTab('mainProcedure')">main_default</a></li>
                                    <li><a class='switchTab' href="#main01" data-toggle="tab" onclick="switchTab('main01')">main_01</a></li>
                                    <li><a class='switchTab' href="#main02" data-toggle="tab" onclick="switchTab('main02')">main_02</a></li>
                                    <li><a class='switchTab' href="#main03" data-toggle="tab" onclick="switchTab('main03')">main_03</a></li>
                                    <li><a class='switchTab' href="#main04" data-toggle="tab" onclick="switchTab('main04')">main_04</a></li>
                                    <li><a class='switchTab' href="#main05" data-toggle="tab" onclick="switchTab('main05')">main_05</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="disabled" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Not Ready yet"><a>State Transition Diagram</a></li>
                            <li class="disabled" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Not Ready yet"><a>State Transition Procedure</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Subroutines<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="sub">
                                    <li><a class='switchTab' href="#sub01" data-toggle="tab" onclick="switchTab('sub01')">run_08</a></li>
                                    <li><a class='switchTab' href="#sub02" data-toggle="tab" onclick="switchTab('sub02')">run_02</a></li>
                                    <li><a class='switchTab' href="#sub03" data-toggle="tab" onclick="switchTab('sub03')">allow_01</a></li>
                                    <li><a class='switchTab' href="#sub04" data-toggle="tab" onclick="switchTab('sub04')">system_01</a></li>
                                    <li><a class='switchTab' href="#sub05" data-toggle="tab" onclick="switchTab('sub05')">run_03</a></li>
                                    <li><a class='switchTab' href="#sub06" data-toggle="tab" onclick="switchTab('sub06')">allow_02</a></li>
                                    <li><a class='switchTab' href="#sub07" data-toggle="tab" onclick="switchTab('sub07')">loading_01</a></li>
                                    <li><a class='switchTab' href="#sub08" data-toggle="tab" onclick="switchTab('sub08')">base_56</a></li>
                                    <li><a class='switchTab' href="#sub09" data-toggle="tab" onclick="switchTab('sub09')">base_05</a></li>
                                    <li><a class='switchTab' href="#sub10" data-toggle="tab" onclick="switchTab('sub10')">export_01</a></li>
                                    <li><a class='switchTab' href="#sub11" data-toggle="tab" onclick="switchTab('sub11')">import_01</a></li>
                                    <li><a class='switchTab' href="#sub12" data-toggle="tab" onclick="switchTab('sub12')">catch_06</a></li>
                                    <li><a class='switchTab' href="#sub13" data-toggle="tab" onclick="switchTab('sub13')">catch_07</a></li>
                                    <li><a class='switchTab' href="#sub14" data-toggle="tab" onclick="switchTab('sub14')">overRun_03</a></li>
                                    <li><a class='switchTab' href="#sub15" data-toggle="tab" onclick="switchTab('sub15')">allow_22</a></li>
                                    <li><a class='switchTab' href="#sub16" data-toggle="tab" onclick="switchTab('sub16')">fail_00</a></li>
                                    <li><a class='switchTab' href="#sub17" data-toggle="tab" onclick="switchTab('sub17')">fail_03</a></li>
                                    <li><a class='switchTab' href="#sub18" data-toggle="tab" onclick="switchTab('sub18')">success_01</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div id="board" class="panel-body" style="height: 480px;">
                        <div class="tab-content" id="tab-list">
                            <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="mainProcedure" style="width: 1120px; height: 440px;"></div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="main01" style="width: 1120px; height: 440px;"></div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="main02" style="width: 1120px; height: 440px;"></div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="main03" style="width: 1120px; height: 440px;"></div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="main04" style="width: 1120px; height: 440px;"></div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="main05" style="width: 1120px; height: 440px;"></div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="stateTransitionDiagram" style="width: 1120px; height: 440px;"></div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="stateTransitionProcedure" style="width: 1120px; height: 440px;"></div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="sub01" style="width: 1120px; height: 440px;"></div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="sub02" style="width: 1120px; height: 440px;"></div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="sub03" style="width: 1120px; height: 440px;"></div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="sub04" style="width: 1120px; height: 440px;"></div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="sub05" style="width: 1120px; height: 440px;"></div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="sub06" style="width: 1120px; height: 440px;"></div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="sub07" style="width: 1120px; height: 440px;"></div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="sub08" style="width: 1120px; height: 440px;"></div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="sub09" style="width: 1120px; height: 440px;"></div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="sub10" style="width: 1120px; height: 440px;"></div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="sub11" style="width: 1120px; height: 440px;"></div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="sub12" style="width: 1120px; height: 440px;"></div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="sub13" style="width: 1120px; height: 440px;"></div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="sub14" style="width: 1120px; height: 440px;"></div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="sub15" style="width: 1120px; height: 440px;"></div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="sub16" style="width: 1120px; height: 440px;"></div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="sub17" style="width: 1120px; height: 440px;"></div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="sub18" style="width: 1120px; height: 440px;"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Call function [swichTab(div)] through the " onclick " event.

```
// tab-content  *** global variable ***
var conID = "";

// select tab
function switchTab(t) {

    var tabID = "tab_"+ t;

    conID = t;

    init();

}
```

It then carries the id of the div to be used in diagram.

```
var diagram = gojs(go.Diagram, conID, {
   ...
}
```

I was able to get an answer by contacting the "GoJS " developer, but I am not sure how to apply it.

///////////////////////////////////////////

Since you still haven't given us the code that you are executing that causes the error, it's hard for us to suggest changes that you should make.

My guess is that your code is something like:

```
  var diagram = go.GraphObject.make(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv", . . .);
```

But the problem is that the "myDiagramDiv" HTMLDivElement already has a go.Diagram associated with it -- that would cause that error.

One solution is not to create a new Diagram but to just use the existing Diagram.  You can get that diagram by calling:

```
  var olddiagram = go.Diagram.fromDiv("myDiagramDiv");
```

Another solution is to disassociate the old diagram from the HTMLDivElement:

```
  var olddiag = go.Diagram.fromDiv("myDiagramDiv");
  if (olddiag) olddiag.div = null;
  var diagram = go.GraphObject.make(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv", . . .);
```

///////////////////////////////////////////

Can you give me a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

This code makes use of the identifier that you are using:

```
    var olddiag = go.Diagram.fromDiv(conID);
    if (olddiag) olddiag.div = null;
    var diagram = go.GraphObject.make(go.Diagram, conID, . . .);
```

For more explanation, read my response that is quoted between lines of slashes in the question.

Comment: add some details please.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I included an explanation above, in the original question, between the lines of slashes.  Note that my answer is code that is exactly the same as the code I gave originally, but now with the string literal replaced by the variable, which I did not know at the time but which was provided in the code given by the questioner.

Comment: @WalterNorthwoods I doubt that you included anything in the original question; Assuming that you are not using two separate accounts to do that, which I think would require some detailed reasining to not be considered against the rules here. And if you indeed did insert that weird non-question part in there, then you made the question very weird, berating yourself for a lack of information.

Comment: Hmmm, I think I have an idea what is/was going on here, but some comments to explain would be very helpful. Please explain. (My guess is that you are "the GoJS developer".... )

Comment: Also, while this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Yes, I am the GoJS developer quoted in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var olddiag = go.Diagram.fromDiv("myDiagramDiv");
if (olddiag) olddiag.div = null;
var diagram = go.GraphObject.make(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv", . . .);
```

I did used this code to solve my question.

Comment: Please explain the additional insight this provides on top of existing answers, especially the one by @WalterNorthwoods. Which you seem to have copied and only changed by replacing (syntactically, but not semantically the parameter to `from Div()`. Otherwise you can take the opportunity to make your answer noticably better than that one by ...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.